# Is there possibility to run a c++ program on my webserver through button click on the html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have done a lot of researching in the last hours only finding results for windows servers.

My problem is that I got a c++ program on a embedded computer which needs to be executed when the user wishes to. That's why I set up a webserver to handle that. So I want to create a html page (already done) with a button called "Start Program", which then executes my c++ program.

I already tried Javascript `child_process` which somehow didn't work and also php `system()` call, which was unhandy because it didn't react to the button click alone, but to refreshing of the page too.

Is there a smart way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: This is way broad. Almost certainly, however, will your server language have some `exec` ability or similar.

Comment: could you provide more info about environment (linux, windows..etc) and show what you already did?

Comment: if you run php on your server, look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279003/execute-c-program-with-php-script (<?PHP
    $output=shell_exec("yourexefile.exe 125 70 127 220 0.5 0.4");
    echo $output;
?>)

Comment: It is certainly possible, if I was in your place I would use the php system, maybe connected with some ajax stuff to avoid reloading the full page.

Comment: Instead of PHP you can also use plain, old CGI.

Comment: im working on a debian system. i tried to use <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"> and then placing a <?php
if (isset($_POST['canispel_click']))
{   
 system("ls");
?> but somehow i get an internal server error when i try to run that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to refresh the page, you can program the button to make an ajax call, using jquery. You can add the following the your html index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
    <!--
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#buttonid').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent page from reloading.
            $.get('/callmyprogram.php');
        });
    });
    -->
</script>
```

Also on your html, the ID of the button must match the selector on the JS code above. The selector `#buttonid` implies that the ID of your button is `buttonid`. So, the html for the button would be something like:

```
<input type="submit" id="buttonid" value="Run C++ program"/>
```

And then you would have `callmyprogram.php` call your c++ program:

```
<?php

exec("/usr/local/bin/myprogram", $output, $ret);
echo "output: $output" . PHP_EOL;
echo "ret: $ret" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: sounds like that is what i need, but as im relatively new to web programming, where do i need to put that &.on'click function? is it a <script>?

Comment: I have edited the answare to better explain where to place the js code.

Comment: thanks, but i get a syntax error at &.('#buttonid').on . do i need to fill in my name of my input type anywhere?

Comment: It must mean something wrong on the PHP side. What happens when you try to access the /callmyprogram.php directaly, like "curl http://localhost:8888/callmyprogram.php"?

Comment: i just edited my comment, the internal server error was my fault. but i dont get where i have to put the name.

Comment: I have edited the answer. By name you mean the "buttonid" selector? It must match the id of the input.

Comment: thanks, i understand that. nonetheless i get SyntaxError: missing name after . operator in line &.('#buttonid').... at the . after &

Comment: small mistake. remove the dot between "$" and "('buttonid')". I have edited the answer.