# Use website to control C++ code raspberry pi

Tags: c++, web, raspberry-pi

I am wondering how to make a website that controls some of the c++ code such as calling a method when clicking on a button.
I googled my ass off however all I could find was for python.

Comment: Welcome to the big world of CLOUD from small world embedded.

Comment: Have the button link to a PHP page and execute the code. [Here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279003/execute-c-program-with-php-script)

Comment: You'll need a webserver running on your pi. There are some tailored for small systems like [lighthttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/). C++ code can be linked through CGI interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can send http request to your c++ backend when clicking on a button.
You can use [Boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) to write you c++ server.
Or you can you can write your server with python or other language framework, and call c++ function in those language.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation is to use a proper web-server that handles most of the page views, including static pages. Then for some specific URL it proxies requests locally to your program which listens for such "API calls" on a specific port.

So for your button, you can have the event handler do an AJAX call to e.g. `http://your-host.example.com/special/path/do_something?some_argument=foo&some_other_argument=123`.

The local web-server then proxies request to `/special/path/` to your program.